# interpreting posterior distribution in JAGS

Tags: r, statistics, probability-density, mcmc, jags

Summing up the posterior probabilities of a discrete distribution gives a value of more than one. Where am I going wrong?

This is the posterior generated by jags

[image: this is the posterior generated by jags]

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the histogram is supposed to be interpreted as a density function, and the probability mass of each bar is therefore the width of the bar times the height of the bar.

Given that interpretation, it looks like the masses sum to approximately 1. The width of each bar appears to be 1/2 and the sum of the heights is about 2 (to judge by eyeball).

If that's not it, you'll have to give more information e.g. show your R script and any data.